# Gcloud auth account used by go sdk

Tags: go, sdk, gcloud

My available `gcloud` auth accounts:

```
▶ gcloud auth list                                                        
         Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        account1@gmail.com
        account2@gmail.com
*       account3@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

When performing `gcloud projects list` I **do** get the list of projects corresponding to the account that above is indicated as ACTIVE (i.e. the one with the asterisk, `account3@gmail.com`)

Nonetheless, when I use the `go` [google cloud sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go) and more specifically the [`cloudresourcemanager`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1#ProjectsListCall) in order to list my projects, I get the ones corresponding to `account1@gmail.com`.

Why isn't the Go SDK using the account that `gcloud` perceives as ACTIVE and how can I instruct it to do so?

The strange part is when I developed some tools using the Python SDK, the behaviour was straightforward and all the SDK calls were indeed using the active account without me having to do any extra configuration steps.

Answer (score 1):

Google's [Golang] Cloud SDKs use [Application Default Credentials (ADCs)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) by default to authenticate to Google Cloud Platforms services.

I suspect (!) at some point, you used [`gcloud auth application-default`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/) with `account1@gmail.com` and so this account is used.

The best practice is to use service accounts rather than human accounts with ADCs and then reference the account using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

Meantime, you may be able to switch to `account3@gmail.com` using the above command to confirm the behavior.